# Create relationship with multipl values

Tags: neo4j, cypher

how can I create an relationship in NEO4J from one node to another node which has multiple vales.

The first node has unique values for the identifier. For example:

Data of the first NodeA:

```
  {
  "c": "11037",
  "b": 15.4,
  "a": 10.0,
  "id": 11137100
  }
```

The second NodeB look like this:

```
  {
  "text": "some text",
  "prio": 1,
  "id": 11137100,
  "value": 0.1
  }
```

But here we have data which has the same id like here:

```
  {
  "text": "some other text",
  "prio": 2,
  "id": 11137100,
  "value": 2.1
  }
```

Now want to create a relationship between both nodes. But if I do things like:

```
MATCH (p:NodeA),(h:NodeB)
WHERE h.id = p.id 
CREATE (p)-[dr:Contains{prio:h.prio}]->(h)
RETURN (dr)
```

I get multiple relationships. I want one NodeA with two Outputs to NodeB.

How can I do it?

Comment: 1. Your `NodeA` does not have the same `id` as the other 2 nodes. Probably a typo? 2. Assuming #1 is corrected, then your query creates 1 relationship from `NodeA` to each `NodeB`, for a total of 2 relationships. Seems reasonable to me. What do you mean by "two Outputs"?

Comment: Sorry this was my vault. It has the same id. I edit it.

Comment: What do you mean by "two Outputs"?

Comment: I want to have NodeA with two Ouputs. With my Statement above I create two NodeA nodes one with value from Node B and one with the other value. So I have two Node A nodes. I want to merge all values which are matched with node A and the id. Is it clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CREATE statement will create a new node/relationship, irrespective if one already exists.

If the intent is to only create a relationship if one does not already exist, I would suggest you do a pre-filter query first, e.g.

```
MATCH (p:NodeA), (h:NodeB)
WHERE h.id = p.id AND NOT (p)-[:Contains{prio:h.prio}]->(h)
//continue your query here
```